# Styling bootstrap data table search filter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to style the search filter in my data table so that the label and the input field appear on a single line.

Right now it is appearing like this:

[image]

Here's the code for the search filter which I can see via the console.

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="ads-table_filter">
<label>
"Search: " 
<input type="text" aria-controls="ads-table">
</label>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
.dataTables_filter {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.dataTables_filter label, .dataTables_filter input {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<div class="dataTables_filter" id="ads-table_filter">
    <label>Search :</label>
    <input type="text" aria-controls="ads-table"/>
</div>
```